# Biased sample same like conditioning on a collider?

Tags: self-study, causality, bayesian-network, dag, collider

I am studying chapter 5 "The many variables & the spurious waffles" of the book Rethinking and trying to answer the following question:

> How is biased sample like conditioning on a collider?

I do understand that when conditioning on a collider will open the path between two or more variables that causally influence a variable. This may result in bias when we estimate the causal association. But I don't understand how bias **sample** could be translated to conditioning on a collider? I assume it may be related to creating variables which are biased sample in such a way that causally influences a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by a biased sample exactly, but we often have the issue of selection bias, which can result from conditioning on a common cause of the intervention and outcome (or generally a variable conditioning on which would unblock a non-causal path between intervention and outcome). For example, let's assume that we run a randomized trial but many patients are missing outcome data. If now we limit our analysis to the subset of patients with non-missing outcome data, i.e., condition on patients having complete data for the outcome, we may end up with a non-causal estimate of the effect of the intervention on the outcome.